# C# - How to write text in file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

How can i write string in file
i tried more methods like :

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("backup.cmd"));
writer.WriteLine("File created using StreamWriter class.");
writer.Close();
```

And :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("backup.cmd"), BackupCMD);
```

and when i try to execute `StreamWriter` only without anything the same error

but the the same result :

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I think the error in the `StreamWriter` initializing.

Comment: So? What is your problem? You get any exception or error message? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Please provide some more info, because your current code shouldn't fire any error.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in one code line using static `WriteAllText` method from `File` class by giving only the file name and the text you want to write:

```
File.WriteAllText("backup.cmd", "File created using File.WriteAllText.");
```

Comment: It is customary to provide comments when you downvote :) I think my post provides an answer to the question *"How can I write string in file"*

Comment: The error always is :
object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Are you sure this `NullReferenceException` is on the line of the code I gave you? Can you provide a screenshot of the exception in Visual Studio?

Comment: Here you can find the exception error : 
http://postimg.org/image/8642cdouh/

and i Checking file exists :: The result true

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with writing the text in file?

Comment: Thanks alot friends i found the error 
i can't access the file in Program files 
i am so sorry i am not so good in english to describe my problem well my languages are Arabic & Deutsch 

 Thanks alot